# How to generate date for the given serial number in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to generate date values for the given serail number (start from getdate and increaed by 1)

```
   SlNr  Date
    1     3/7/2013
    2     ?
    3     ?
    4     ?
    5     ?
    6     ?
    7     ?
    8     3/14/2013
    .     ?
    .     ?
```

How to write sql query. Please help

Comment: What does adding 1 to a `DATETIME` mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
with cte as
(select 1 Sno, convert(date,GETDATE(),103) mydate
union all

select Sno+1,DATEADD(dd,1,mydate) from cte where Sno<=10)

select * from cte
```

Change `WHERE` clause to get more dates.You can use `Insert into` before `select` to insert the data in some table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `DATEADD()` function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186819.aspx).

```
SELECT SlNr, DATEADD(DAY, SlNr, GETDATE()) FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your shown results:

```
declare @firstdate date = '20130307' --Your first date in yyyymmdd format

select slnr, dateadd(day, (slnr-1), @firstdate) [date]
from yourTable
order by slnr
```

If you use `getdate()`, results will be different for everyday. If that what you need simply `replace @firstdate with getdate()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `DATEADD`

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT slnr, 
                date, 
                RN = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         ORDER BY slnr) 
         FROM   dates) 
UPDATE cte 
SET    date = Dateadd(dd, cte.RN - 1, GETDATE()) 
WHERE  date IS NULL;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e627/4/0)